# How to check is a product simple or variable INSIDE THE LOOP on the shop page?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I need to remove the loop add to cart button and add single add to cart button instead of it to products on the shop page, but only for simple, the variable have their own functions.
I try

```
if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart',10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 12); 
}
```

But it doesn't save, shows the error

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_type() on null in wp-content/themes/lafka/incl/woocommerce-functions.php:1406
```

How to check the type correctly?
global $product before didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The $product variable is not properly defined when you are trying to call the is_type() method on it.  You can use the is_product() function provided by WooCommerce:

```
if ( is_product() ) {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 12 );
    }
}
```